# Python Import File from Shared Directory

Tags: python

I am new to python so apologies for the newness of the question.

A description of what I want to do:
I have this folder structure:
c:\PythonScripts\SharedFunctions
C:\PythonScripts\Test\RebuildSpatialIndex\RebuildIndexes.py
C:\PythonScripts\Prod\RebuildSpatialIndex\RebuildIndexes.py

I would like the RebuildIndexes.py to be able to use the function in c:\PythonScripts\SharedFunctions.

How do I do that properly in python?

Comment: You will have to drop an empty `__init__.py` inside the shared_functions folder to make it into a package. Then either put it in site_packages inside python installtion or add the folder to sys.path. Btw, in python we use underscored names for modules(scripts, packages) rather than camelcase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you want to import a module, the module's parent directory must be in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

So, in your case, you would add `c:\PythonScripts\SharedFunctions` to your `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Windows, so I don't know how to set your PYTHONPATH there (which will enable you to have any Python scripts find your local libraries). The documentation for using Python on Windows [(Python 2)](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html) [(Python 3)](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) will help.

To add to the path from within a program, use

```
import sys
sys.path.append(path_to_local_libraries)
```